# MYSQL events in PHP after XML update

Tags: php, mysql

**I have script that**

- copy xml file from external source to my webserver,
- import xml file to mysql database (code, name, price, quantity) by REPLACE (updates existed rows and inserts new one when available),
- sends email which products have quantity <=0 (a list of all products with that quantity),
- show database data in html table,

**Im looking for hint's or ideas "how to" show:**

1) alarm that one product has changed to 0

2) price change

3) new added products

4) quantity changed to <10

upon every update process?

I don't want code - just ideas. Im not a PHP/MYSQL pro but i want to learn. Don't blame me.

Comment: *Don't blame me* not sure what we have to blame you for.  The main thing people usually ask for though is some form of evidence that you have made some effort in solving this prior to asking a question here.

Answer (score 0):

Question #1] The trigger for the alarm should reside on the code block that updates the product. In high level:

```
 IF product_ordered 
     execute_order(); 
     IF product_qty <= 0     
        trigger_alarm();
```

Question #2 & #3 and #4] Can be build in with the same logic below

```
  IF update_product
     execute_update();
     IF product.price != product.new_price
        trigger_alarm();
```

Also you can look into CRON Jobs, MySQL Triggers as a possible solution. I hope this helps